# Tomcat doesn't load WAR files

Tags: tomcat, war

I am using Tomcat on CentOS and I am trying to deploy two WAR files, let's call it app1.war and app2.war. But when I try to load it through browser by clicking `localhost ip/app1` or `localhost ip/app2`, it just displays blank screen. I've checked the server.xml file and there it already said `autoDeploy=true`. I have no idea what caused this.

Comment: Did you run `startup.sh`? Did `app1.war` unzip success?

Comment: I start the service with `systemctl start tomcat`. Is there any different? Yes, the file can be unzipped.

Comment: Maybe you config routing incorrect.

Comment: which config routing? Can you expand more?

Comment: What does `catalina.out` say? Does it mention starting your applications? No errors?